# Why second console.log output is the function body rather than 20?

Tags: javascript, iife

```js
(function b() {
  console.log(b);
  b = 20;
  console.log(b);
})();
```

I wrote this JavaScript IIFE.
The first `console.log` logs the function body.
Then the `b` variable is created with value `20`.
The second `console.log` also logs the function body.
Why not `20`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `b` is constant and cannot be assigned to. You're in non-strict mode, so the assignment just silently does nothing, but if you use [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) you will get an error, highlighting the problem.

```js
(function b() {
  'use strict';
  console.log(b);
  b = 20;         // Throws an exception
  console.log(b); // Never gets to here
})();
```

Answer (score 3):

Let's break down what's happening in your code:

```js
(function b() {
  console.log(b); // This refers to the function itself
  b = 20; // Here you're trying to assign a value to the function, but it won't work as expected
  console.log(b); // This still refers to the function itself
})();
```

1. The IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) is defined with the name `b`. Inside the function, the identifier `b` refers to the function itself.
2. The first `console.log(b)` outputs the function definition, as `b` refers to the function at this point.
3. The line `b = 20;` is encountered. Here's where things get interesting: since `b` was declared as the function itself, this line tries to assign the value `20` to the function `b`. However, functions in JavaScript are objects, and you can assign properties to them, but this doesn't change their behavior as a function.
4. The second `console.log(b)` still refers to the function, so it outputs the same function definition as before.

In essence, the assignment `b = 20` doesn't change `b` still refers to the function, `20` in this `b` inside.